# tableView entries with Ä Ö Ü not showing

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

How do I set up the tableView section index to show Ä Ö or Ü (i.e. german umlauts)

(Using XCode-6.4 / iOS-8.4.1 / Swift 1.2):

I intend to create a tableView in iOS showing table-entries with german words. I achieved creating a tableView showing words in english.

But right now, my tableView is not showing any entry that has a beginning-letter of Ä,ä Ö,ö or Ü,ü (i.e. german umlauts).

Reading some articles about localization, I am still not getting the desired result.

I am useing a "UILocalizedIndexCollation". But for some reason, it only contains 27-entries (A-Z, plus #). But not the desired umlauts !

What do I have to do in order to get the additional collation.sectionIndexTitles ??

Here is my code :

```
let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation() as! UILocalizedIndexedCollation
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return db.getNrDBEntriesPerSection(playerRealm, sectString: collation.sectionIndexTitles[section] as! String)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return (collation.sectionTitles[section] as! String)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return collation.sectionIndexTitles.count
}

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]! {

    return collation.sectionIndexTitles
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {

    return collation.sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex(index)
}
```

There are two localizations defined in my app:
[image]

The .plist contains two languages as can be seen in the picture below:
[image]

The bundle contains two language-folders:
[image]

Comment: Did you set the device/simulator to German language?

Comment: @MartinR: That wouldn't help non-German users, who still wouldn't see those entries.

Comment: Yes, I did set the device/simulator to German. But as gnasher729 mentioned that is not exactly what I am asking for....

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember the details, but you need to pass all the strings to UILocalizedIndexedCollation, which will add each string (including those starting with Ä for example) to one of the characters in the index.

Alternatively, change db.getNrDBEntriesPerSection to do a case insensitive, diacritical insensitive comparison.

Comment: How do you add "all the strings to UILocalizedIndexCollation" ?? I tried: collation.sectionIndexTitles.append("Ä")   But this won't work... What do you exactly mean by "change db.getNrDBEntriesPerSection to do a case insensitive, diacritical insensitive comparison ?? Can you make examples for both suggestions ? Thank you very much!